# Having problems saving boolean and int to sharedPrefs

Tags: android, boolean, int, save, sharedpreferences

I'm trying to create an endgame activity for my Hangman game for android and i'm having some trouble committing values OTHER than strings.

Here is my main activity:

```
package com.assignment.hangman;
import android.app.Activity;


public class HangmanActivity extends Activity {
    public static final String GAME_PREFERENCES = "Game Preferences";
    public static final String GAME_LOGIC = "Game Logic";
    public static final String GAME_LOGIC_GUESS = "Guessed letter";
    public static final String GAME_LOGIC_SCORE_STRING = "Unknow score";
    public static final boolean GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE = false;
}
```

I get the sharedprefs like this:

```
mGameSettings = getSharedPreferences("GAME_PREFERENCES", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

And this is where something goes wrong when committing the changes to the editor:

```
public void finishGame() {
        //Commit different game variables so they can be used in the end game activity  
        Editor editor = mGameSettings.edit();
        editor.putString(GAME_LOGIC_SCORE_STRING, (tries + " of " + numberOfLives + " used"));
        if (tries != numberOfLives){
            editor.putBoolean("GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE", true);
        }
        editor.commit();
        // Launch end game Activity
        startActivity(new Intent(HangmanGameActivity.this, HangmanEndActivity.class));
    }
```

And after changing activity i refetch the values like this:

```
        if (mGameSettings.contains("GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE")) {
        Log.i(GAME_DEBUG, "Succes");
        boolean winLoose = mGameSettings.getBoolean("GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE", false);
        if (winLoose) {
            winLooseView.setText(R.string.you_win);
        } else {
            winLooseView.setText(R.string.you_loose);
    }
    }
```

But somehow only the String is being committed correctly. I guess the boolean value reverts to the default value of false.

Could someone help me shed some light on this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you only want to move the data from one activity to another I would attach it to the Intent.
Writing it to shared memory means accessing the phone storage and that is really slow.

You could it do in this way:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HangmanGameActivity.this, HangmanEndActivity.class);
intent.putExtra(GAME_LOGIC_SCORE_STRING, tries + " of " + numberOfLives + " used"):
intent.putExtra("GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE", true);  
startActivity(intent);
```

In the EndActivity you would do:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String gameString = intent.getStringExtra(GAME_LOGIC_SCORE_STRING, "default value");
boolean win = intent.getBooleanExtra(GAME_LOGIC_WIN_LOOSE, false);
```

Comment: Wow that was easy. Thanks alot for the quick response.